# Details of Hilbert's proof of the continuum hypothesis

Tags: set-theory

Toward the end of his paper on the infinite Hilbert sketched his proof of the continuum hypothesis. [D. Hilbert: "Über das Unendliche", Mathematische Annalen 95 (1925)] Can experts on Hilbert give more details of his proof than are published there?

Comment: This question is already answered at length by Noah Schweber on Math Overflow, [Hilbert's alleged proof of the Continuum Hypothesis in “On the Infinite”](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272028/hilberts-alleged-proof-of-the-continuum-hypothesis-in-on-the-infinite)

Comment: Very interesting. The elaborate work of Dreben and Kanamori reduces the probability to near zero that more of Hilbert's writings can be unearthed.